# sum/avg/mean ops of tf.keras.backend do not work correctly over batch axis

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

When adding an aggregation function on the batch axis (axis=0), everything is fine, as long as the batchsize is <=32, with batchsize >32 the output shape changes.

```
def model_test(samples, parameters):

    input_shape = (parameters)
    in_ = keras.layers.Input(input_shape, batch_size=samples)

    l1_size1 = parameters//2
    l2_size2 = parameters//3

    l1 = keras.layers.Dense(l1_size1,activation='relu')(in_)
    l2 = keras.layers.Dense(l2_size2,activation='relu')(l1)

    out_max = keras.backend.max(l2,axis=0)

    model = keras.models.Model(in_, out_max)

    return model
```

creating the model for 32 samples:

```
Model: "functional_246"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_146 (InputLayer)       [(32, 10)]                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_66 (Dense)             (32, 5)                   55        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_67 (Dense)             (32, 3)                   18        
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Max_138 (TensorF [(3,)]                    0         
=================================================================
Total params: 73
Trainable params: 73
Non-trainable params: 0
```

running the model and display the real output shape:

```
x = tf.random.normal((orders ,parameters))
result = model.predict(x)
print(result.shape)


(3,)
```

creating it for 33 samples, creates a similar model, with the same output and the same number of parameters, as expected:

```
orders = 33
parameters = 10
model = model_test(orders, parameters)
model.summary()

Model: "functional_248"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_147 (InputLayer)       [(33, 10)]                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_68 (Dense)             (33, 5)                   55        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_69 (Dense)             (33, 3)                   18        
_________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Max_139 (TensorF [(3,)]                    0         
=================================================================
Total params: 73
Trainable params: 73
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

but the real output shape doubles:

```
x = tf.random.normal((orders ,parameters))
result = model.predict(x)
print(result.shape)

(6,)
```

The observed output is always a multiple of batchsize//32 + 1 and hence does not match a actual expected output.

This was tested with tensorflow 2.3.1 same on GPU and CPU.

adding a further dimension, gives the same output, so this really only happens on axis=0

```
def model_test(samples, parameters):

    input_shape = (samples, parameters)
    in_ = keras.layers.Input(input_shape, batch_size=None)

    l1_size1 = parameters//2
    l2_size2 = parameters//3

    l1 = keras.layers.Dense(l1_size1,activation='relu')(in_)
    l2 = keras.layers.Dense(l2_size2,activation='relu')(l1)

    out_max = keras.backend.max(l2,axis=1)

    model = keras.models.Model(in_, out_max)

    return model
```

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue, I think it is a bug, can you raise the issue on GitHub, If you want I can raise the Bug for you.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reproduce. I will write a ticket and link it. Sorry for the late response